# Convert Hexadecimal String to single precision ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, floating-point

I have an array of Strings, each representing a 32-bit single precision Float, passed into ActionScript. I need to convert these Strings back into their single precision float representation. N.B the floating point numbers can range from -1 to 1

eg.

```
3930D934 = 0.0001686558243818581   
38AD2D39 = 0.00008257706213044003
```

I seem to be losing precision when converting the String to any other AS3 datatype.

All suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ByteArray class to convert it to a Number without precision loss:

```
var ba: ByteArray = new ByteArray();
ba.writeUnsignedInt(parseInt("3930D934", 16));
ba.position = 0;
trace(ba.readFloat()); // returns 0.0001686558243818581
```